# C++ Reference Creation Syntax

Tags: c++, reference

When creating a reference in C++ why does the compiler request a value and not an address.
For example:

```
int i;
int &j = i;
```

is valid.

```
int i;
int &j = *&i;
```

is valid.

```
int i;
int &j = &i;
```

is incorrect. If you are equating the address, why does it request a value?

Comment: A reference is an alias, so it needs a name (not an address) to refer to. _"...Declares a named variable as a reference, that is, __an alias__ to an already-existing object or function...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: The language could have been designed to initialize a reference with an address, and not with an object. But it was designed the other way, which is safer.

Comment: You seem to think that a reference is just the same as a pointer, just with different syntax, but that is not the case. As others have mentioned, a reference is an alias, not a pointer. The compiler may treat some references as pointers, and others like you are just using the original variable directly.

Comment: *If you are equating the address...*  A reference is not equating the address.

Comment: `&` means different things in different contexts. The `&` in `int &j` has a different meaning from the `&` in `&i`. They're the same symbol, but they're not the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference is an alias to an **already-existing object or function**. In particular case, this is an **lvalue reference**, so it is a reference to an lvalue, the address of an object is not an lvalue.

> A **reference to T** can be initialized with an **object of type T**, a
> **function of type T**, or an object implicitly **convertible to T**.

Considering this, the error we get, when try this says for itself:

```
invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ // from the &i to the &i
```

But for example, we can do this:

```
int i;
int *&&j = &i; // j is an rvalue reference to pointer to int
```

Also, as was [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) in the comments, you should not confuse the `&` when it is used in **a declaration**, and when it is used as **an operator** (i.e. the [address-of-operator](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)).

You may benefit from looking at the documentation:

[Reference Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) and [Reference declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Answer (score 0):

> why does the compiler request a value

It doesn't request a value. You have the wrong frame of mind. All it needs is some expression that identifies an object. The variable name `i` is such an expression.

In some contexts, expressions that designate object cause an access to a stored value (for instance `i = i + i;` would incur an access). But not *every* use of `i` will cause its value to be read. So for instance when references are bound to it, `i` doesn't need to be (and indeed isn't) accessed for its value.

In the same vain, `*&i` doesn't *always* access the value of `i`. It's an expression, where the C++ standard says that `*` and `&` "collapse" here to simply designating `i` (with some minutia), but no access happens just due to using the operators themselves.